# R plyr inconsistent output vector names

Tags: r, plyr

I've traced a bug in my code down to how `plyr 1.8` doesn't name output consistently:

```
> laply(list(1), identity)     # output vector has name
1 
1 
> laply(list(1,2), identity)   # output vector unnamed
[1] 1 2
```

Do the plyr `--ply` functions come with any options to prevent names from appearing in output (i.e. I always want unnamed output vectors)?

Comment: Not an answer, but you can often just drop down to the base R `sapply` for many use cases of `laply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just wrapping the calls in `unname()` to drop any names, as in:

```
unname(laply(list(1), identity))
# [1] 1

unname(laply(list(1,2), identity))
# [1] 1 2
```